# Why does this Web2Py ajax call fail to return the value of a variable?

Tags: ajax, web2py

Here is the relevant snippet from my Web2Py view:

```
{{for candidate in rows:}}
    <div class="well col-sm-12">
        <button type="button" name="up_button" onclick="ajax('{{=URL('default', 'arrow_button_callback')}}', ['name'], 'target')" class="fa fa-caret-up arrow-up fa-4x"></button>
        <span>{{=candidate.votes}}</span>
        <button type="button" name="down_button" onclick="ajax('{{=URL('default', 'arrow_button_callback')}}', ['name'], 'target')" class="fa fa-caret-down arrow-down fa-4x"></button>
        {{=IMG(_src=URL('photos',candidate.path_to_photo), _alt="Photo of Candidate")}}
        {{=candidate.name}}
        <div id="target"></div>
   </div>
{{pass}}
```

And the relevant snippet from my Web2Py controller:

```
def arrow_button_callback():
    response.flash = str(request.post_vars.name)
    return request.post_vars.name
```

So why do I see the string "None" in my target div (and in my flash)?

Thank you for your help. I read chapter 11 of the Web2Py book and I'm still confused.

I really want to be able to pass candidate.id (depending on which row's button was pressed) and the button direction to controller variables. Please let me know if there's a better way to do this.

--Benjamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the web2py documentation (emphasis added):

> `ajax(url, [name1, name2, ...], target)`
>
> It asynchronously calls the url (first argument), passes the values of the ***field inputs*** with the name equal to one of the names in the list (second argument)...

In your code, your second argument is `['name']`. However, there is no input field with the name "name" anywhere, so no "name" variable gets posted to web2py (therefore, `request.post_vars.name` is `None`, which is the default value returned whenever you attempt to get a variable that does not exist in `request.post_vars`).

In this case, because you are not placing any data in form input fields, you can simply ignore the second argument to `ajax()`. Instead, pass the relevant data via the URL itself:

```
   {{url = URL('default', 'arrow_button_callback',
               vars=dict(id=candidate.id, direction='up'))}}
   <button type="button" name="up_button" onclick="ajax('{{=url}}', [], 'target')"
    class="fa fa-caret-up arrow-up fa-4x"></button>
```

Then in the `arrow_button_callback` controller, you can access the candidate id via `request.get_vars.id` (or just `request.vars.id`). And you can access the arrow direction via `request.vars.direction`. Create a new URL for the "down" button, with `direction='down'`.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to pass through candidate.id. I just had to add two curly braces to the end of the variable declaration. Now I'm just confused about how to send the clicked button direction...

Comment: Oops, just fixed it. As for communicating the button direction, just add that to the URL query string as well (see my updated answer).